# Is there an alternative way to hide divs and slide them up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having issues with this script including not working on latest Firefox & IE versions!
I'm using this script to hide divs that have class of container and show the one with id #home.And then show elements depending on  href="#customid.

Although I have it working on a live website, could it be an issue with running a webpage locally? or could it be a problem of html markup which containes only divs that are well closed.

In general, is their any "better" way of doing this?

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
// hides all DIVs with the CLASS container
// and displays the one with the ID 'home' only
$(".container").css("display","none");
$("#home").css("display","block");

// makes the navigation work after all containers have bee hidden 
showViaLink($("aside button#navigation a"));

// listens for any navigation keypress activity
$(document).keypress(function(e)
{
    switch(e.which)
    {
        // user presses the "a"
        case 97:    showViaKeypress("#home");
                    break;  

        // user presses the "s" key
        case 115:   showViaKeypress("#about");
                    break;

        // user presses the "d" key
        case 100:   showViaKeypress("#contact");
                    break;

        // user presses the "f" key
        case 102:   showViaKeypress("#awards");
                    break;

        // user presses the "g" key 
        case 103:   showViaKeypress("#links");
       }
       });
       });

// shows a given element and hides all others
function showViaKeypress(element_id)
{
$(".container").css("display","none");
// if multiple keys are pressed rapidly this will hide all but the last pressed key's div
$(".container").hide(1);
$(element_id).slideDown("slow");
}

// shows proper DIV depending on link 'href'
function showViaLink(array)
{
array.each(function(i)
{   
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".container").css("display","none");
        $(target).slideDown("slow");
    });
});
}
```

Comment: $(".container").css("display","none");
    $("#home").css("display","block");
    

can be replaced by:

    $(".container").hide();
    $("#home").show();

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way, which would greatly "simplify" your script.

### [Here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/507f0aef32154b43cd7aaac078f2c12c)

**html**

```
<div id="home" data-hotkey="97" class="container">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
</div>
<div id="about" data-hotkey="115" class="container">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
<div id="contact" data-hotkey="100" class="container">
    <a href="#contact">contact</a>
</div>
<div id="awards" data-hotkey="102" class="container">
    <a href="#awards">Awards</a>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #bada55;
  transition: height 0.2s;
  text-align: center;
}
.container > a {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container.hide {
  display: hidden;
  height: 0px;
}
.container:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #85da55;
}
.container:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #55dac5;
}
.container:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: #9055da;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(function() {
  // cache containers
  var $containers = $('.container');
  
  // hide all but home
  $containers.not('#home').addClass('hide');
    
  $(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    var hotkey = e.which,
        $keyContainer = $('[data-hotkey='+e.which+']');
    
    // if not in hotkeys, return
    if (!$keyContainer.length) return;

    $containers.addClass('hide');
    $keyContainer.removeClass('hide');
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks, although could you please add real content example so i can see how i would add it to my project, the codepen isn't working as it should as the navbar hrefs are hidden, also I don't have experience in jade nor less.

Comment: what do you mean? you want a link to click as well? Or you just want to highlight on keypress?

Comment: @Sup3r you should make a js fiddle with you actual markup. That would greatly help, so I don't have to try and figure out what it is based on js.

Comment: oh, are you trying to change the content area, based on which nav clicked? if so, simple!